How to optimize React application performance when rendering large lists with dynamic content?
I'm working on a React application where I need to render a large list of items, and each item has dynamic content that can change frequently. I'm looking for advanced strategies to optimize the performance and ensure smooth user experience. Here are some details about my current implementation:

Data Source: The list data comes from a REST API that provides real-time updates.
Rendering: Each item in the list has multiple nested components with different state requirements.
State Management: Using Redux for global state and Context API for local component state.
Virtualization: Implemented react-window for virtual scrolling, but still facing performance issues when items update frequently.
Memoization: Using React.memo and useMemo where applicable, but the improvements are minimal.
Batching Updates: Tried batching state updates with unstable_batchedUpdates, but the performance gain is not significant.

export type CreateTemplateType = {
    projectId: string;
    environmentId: string;
    name: string;
    description?: string;
    iconId?: string;
    selectedColor?: string;
    parentId?: string;
};

solution in more than 20 chars
